# Location Manager unwrapping error only on First launch

Tags: swift, core-location

Each time i install my App on a new device i get an Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value during the very first launch!

But subsequent launches are fine and do not crash.

This is the line the crashes

```
let Startlat = String(LocationManager.sharedInstance.location.coordinate.latitude)
```

Im unsure what can cause this as it only occurs during the very first launch!

Comment: try to refuse the permission and it'll crash every launch

Comment: That code shouldn't compile, since LocationManager.sharedInstance.location is an Optional.

Answer (score 0):

First launch involves an asynchronous user permission so `location` will be nil at time of accessing with `!`

```
var location: CLLocation! /// <<<<< ! should be ?
```

, you need to do

```
if let loc = LocationManager.sharedInstance.location as? CLLocation {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A singleton class instance is initialised only when you access a property of the class or call a method of the class. Initially location property will be nil.
So create a start method like this and call the method in AppDelegate

And don't declare the location property in LocationManager class as explicitly unwrapped optional

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        LocationManager.shared.start()
        print(LocationManager.shared.location?.coordinate.latitude)//will never crash
        return true
    }
```

**LocationManager.swift**

```
class LocationManager {
    static let shared = LocationManager()
    var location: CLLocation?
    var manager = CLLocationManager()
    private init() {

    }
    func start() {
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        LocationManager.shared.location = locations.last
    }
}
```